# Setting up SRV records for a Minecraft server

Tags: domain-name-system, port, gameserver, srv-record

I have a Minecraft server listening on port 25566, and I'm trying to set up an `SRV` record on my domain so you can access that game server by just typing the IP address: `play.example.com`.

After many tries It seems I can't get it to work. Here's what I've done:

1. Set up an A record pointing to my server:

   ```
   Name: play.example.com    Destination IP Address: 123.4.5.6
   ```
2. Set up an `SRV` record like this:

   ```
   Name: _gserver._tcp.play.example.com Priority: 0 Weight: 0 Port: 25566 Value: play.example.com
   ```

When I try to access play.example.com It doesn't redirect me to the port.
For some reason the `A` record works, but the `SRV` one doesn't.

Any idea why this isn't working?

Comment: What game is this? Does it *support* SRV records?

Comment: It's minecraft, yes It does support them since v1.3.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The protocol that `minecraft` uses is `minecraft`, not `gserver`.

The `SRV` record should be

- Name: _minecraft._tcp.play.gameserver.com
- Priority: 0
- Weight: 0
- Port: 25566
- Value: play.gameserver.com